# Identifying plant species (cactus)

Tags: identification, cactus

I would be grateful if someone could help me with identifying this cacti I bought. I did some research and concluded it could be Pilosocereus chrysostele. But I am not really sure as there are some similar cacti out there.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Your cactus is a *Pilosocereus chrysostele*; There are many cacti which are similar in appearance, and *P. chrysostele* is a popular variety: They're robust and attractive. Maybe carefully check how yours was set in the container, there should be some coarse gravel in the bottom, & a hole(s) in the bottom for drainage. Nice healthy looking cactus!